# Unable to retrieve multiple rows using cursor from database table using stored procedure DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, mule

I am trying to retrieve multiple rows from table using stored procedure and it doesn't work for me. My stored procedure is as follows,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE E_Enquiry 
    (IN SourceQueue1 VARCHAR(30) ) LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN 
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR 
        select CreationTime 
        from ms.Exception_Message 
        where SourceQueue = SourceQueue1; 

    open c1; 
END;
```

I am trying to call the stored procedure from Mule Anypoint Studio using the  Database connector and have seen the result as null when I print the payload with a logger. If I try to modify the query as it returns a single row it works (without using cursor).

Please help to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, declaring and opening cursor is generally how one returns a result set from a stored procedure.  I know you know this, so your comment confuses me.

Comment: @Charles - actually, I didn't.  Thanks for teaching me!  I guess I'm a little too used to functions and imperative languages - I feel like the examples I'd seen before were explicitly returning a cursor type.

Answer (score 2):

What platform and version of DB2?

Try the adding

- DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
- WITH RETURN TO CLIENT

Like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE E_Enquiry 
    (IN SourceQueue1 VARCHAR(30) ) 
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN 
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR 
        select CreationTime 
        from ms.Exception_Message 
        where SourceQueue = SourceQueue1; 

    open c1; 
END;
```